# Why popover does not work with bootstrap-table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-tooltip, bootstrap-popover, bootstrap-table

I use bootstrap-table with some bootstrap-popover and or tooltip. When i resize the window or use some table function (example: search or toggle or sort).Then the popover or tooltip does not work any more. (for example the tooltip become as a standard html tooltip.). What i miss? or it is some problem? Any help is welcome! I tried with a standard bootstrap table and i do not find this problem.

I just add a JSFiddle here
[test with tooltip and popover](https://jsfiddle.net/jipexu/8vgk5626/10/)

It's work now please see here
[solved](https://jsfiddle.net/jipexu/m2pb6qky/)

Thanks for the help of djhvscf on github

so for the js i have this

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
})
```

and for html

```
<table id ="lst_art_adm" data-toggle="table" 
            data-striped="true" 
            data-search="true"
            data-show-toggle="true"
            data-mobile-responsive="true"
        >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-sortable="true">ID</th>
                    <th>Titre</th>
                    <th>Sujet</th>
                    <th>Fonctions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

     <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td align="left" width="80%">Un autre article <i>(archive)</i></td>
        <td>NPDS<a href="index.php?op=newtopic&amp;topic=1" class="tooltip">NPDS</a></td>
```

```
     <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td align="left" width="80%"><a data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" href="article.php?sid=13" data-content="" title="13" data-html="true" class="">test article</a></td>
        <td>Modules<a href="index.php?op=newtopic&amp;topic=2" class="tooltip">Modules</a></td>
```

...

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Because i have many problem to post this i forgot to say the plugin used is bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.

Comment: just add the code (truncated for the table...) here is with popover if i replace with tooltip it is the same problem .. only work if i not resize the window and if i not use the table fonctions ...

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: tested with Safari and FF .. same

Comment: @ barbara thanks. no any error on the console ...